# Angular : Should unsubscribe from forkJoin piped by shareReplay(1)?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, rxjs

I want to know if it is necessary to **unsubscribe** from Observables made with `forkJoin([..])` using a set of HttpClient Observables piped by `shareReplay(..)` operator?

I read about `forkJoin(..)` that it unsubscribe automatically, but i don't know if it's the same case when piped with `shareReplay(..)` operator, because i read that this one can leads to a **Memory Leaks** problems if it's misused.

My following example is used to cache Http Requests results and here is my chunk of codes:

Service:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class HttpcatcherService {
  codeNafsObservable$: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private positionservice: PositionserviceService) {}

  getAllEntities(refresh?: boolean): Observable<any> {
    if (!this.codeNafsObservable$ || refresh) {
      this.codeNafsObservable$ = forkJoin([
        this.positionservice.getPosts(), // returns Observable
        this.positionservice.getComments(), // returns Observable
      ]).pipe(
        map((result) => {
          return {
            secondNaf: result[0],
            thirdNaf: result[1],
          };
        }),
        shareReplay(1)
      );
    }
    return this.codeNafsObservable$;
  }
}
```

My component (knowing that i use the same way/logic in different components also):

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private httpCat: HttpcatcherService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpCat
    .getAllEntities()
    .subscribe(
     (result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The advice is to always unsubscribe. Even better advice would be to never subscribe in the first place 

Comment: Thank you @MikeOne for the advice, i really appreciate it ! to be honest, I still really confused about the usage of ` shareReplay(..)` with `forJoin(..)` , because my idea is that i read about `even if we unsubscribe from an Observable piped by shareReplay(..), it still be an issue if we don't handle it with countRef(...) operator` , but i still not sure about this, that's why i want to have a detailed technical answer 

Comment: I think you should unsubscribe in your component, the question is not related to any rxjs operator but to the act of subscribe, then you should manage your subscriptions to avoid memory leaks as you said

Comment: @RebaiAhmed thank you for your answer ! i'm totally agree with you, i often unsubscribe subscriptions to avoid any doubt, but what i wanted to learn from this question is exactly the behaviour of forJoin(..) and the shareReplay(..) operations to avoid any confusion, because i found a lot of articles talking about shareReplay as a dangerous operator if we misconfigure it , but after the answer of Picci below, i already got the correct way to understand it ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the use of `forkJoin` together with `shareReplay` does not cause any memory leak issue. The reason is the following:

- `forkJoin` notifies when all the Observables passed in as parameters `complete`. In this case, since the Observable passed to `forkJoin` are related to http calls, they complete just after the http call returns. therefore as soon as both http calls return, the Observable created by `forkJoin` notifies and then completes.
- The effect of `shareReplay` is to create an internal cache that makes sure that any subscription will get the last value notified by upstream. In this case, the last value notified by upstream is the only value notified by the Observable created by `forkJoin`

The risk of memory leaks or, at least, the risk of uncontrolled execution of code with `shareRepley` comes when the source Observable is an infinite stream (for instance a stream created with `interval`). In this case, `shareReplay` creates an Observable which never completes, even if there are no subscribers, unless the `refCount` property of `ShareReplayConfig` is set to `true`.

This behavior is explained in details [in the documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay#reference-counting).

In any case this is not a risk you run, since the source Observable you have will emit only once and then complete.

Answer (score 2):

As of RxJS 7, `shareReplay(1)` is a wrapper around share with the following parameters:

```
  share({
    connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1),
    resetOnComplete: false,
    resetOnError: false,
    resetOnRefCountZero: false
  })
```

If you want finer control over how `shareReplay` works, use `share` instead and set the configuration options as you need.

For example, if you set `resetOnRefCountZero` to true, then when there are no longer any subscribers the inner ReplaySubject will be unsubscribed.

Comment: thank you a lot ! this is very awsome solution ! but my only issu is that i was obligated to use `shareReplay(..)` because i'm working on an old project with old angular version , but your solution is really nice to help me for my upcoming projects too